# Trouble Creating Shuffled Slideshow of Gifs from Imgur Album

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am currently working in JSFiddle to figure out a way to pull gifs from my Ingur album into a fullscreen slideshow that is on permanent shuffle.

I have a Twitch stream channel, and we are looking for a forever-looping fullscreen canvas of random gifs from my album.

Being somewhat of a javascript newb, this is what I came up with...

```
    function slideSwitch() {
    var $active = $('#slideshow div.active');
    if ( $active.length == 0 ) {
    var slides = $('#slideshow div');
    $active = slides.eq(Math.floor(Math.random() * slides.length));
    }
    var $next =  $active.next().length ? $active.next()
        : $('#slideshow div:first');
    $active.addClass('last-active');
    $next.css({opacity: 0.0})
        .addClass('active')
        .animate({opacity: 1.0}, 1000, function() {
            $active.removeClass('active last-active');
        });
    }
    $(function() {
        setInterval( function(){slideSwitch()}, 10000 );
    });
```

For Reference:  http://jsfiddle.net/ectokooler/upusN/

I realize a few things have not been touched (fullscreen, etc) but I have been working on transitions and getting the images to appear (again.. newb :P).

Is there anyone out there who can help me figure out how to make the gif stretch fullscreen (maintaining aspect ration) and play continuously in a shuffle?

I am happy to populate the playlist of URL's until I dive into the imgur api.
Imgur album for reference (https://i.stack.imgur.com/TMRJi.jpg)

Thank you in advance

Ecto

Answer (score 1):

Just adjust the `height` and `width` untill it's fullscreen.

If that doesn't work try putting your gif's in an `<iframe>`